# goreleaser signing using gon - bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable

Tags: go, gon, goreleaser

I am trying to sign my golang using goreleaser - and eventually distribute using Homebrew. But this will require signing with Apple Developer ID to be able to distribute to MacOs.

Have you seen the following error using [gon](https://github.com/mitchellh/gon) and fixed it?

yaml sample from [here](https://goreleaser.com/customization/sign/#executables)

```
# This is an example .goreleaser.yml file with some sane defaults.
# Make sure to check the documentation at http://goreleaser.com
before:
  hooks:
    # You may remove this if you don't use go modules.
    - go mod tidy
    # you may remove this if you don't need go generate
    - go generate ./...

builds:
- binary: foo
  id: foo
  goos:
  - linux
  goarch:
  - amd64
# notice that we need a separated build for the MacOS binary only:
- binary: foo
  id: appbrew-macos
  goos:
  - darwin
  goarch:
  - amd64
  hooks:
    post: gon gon.hcl
```

### gon.hcl file

```
# The path follows a pattern
# ./dist/BUILD-ID_TARGET/BINARY-NAME

source = ["."]
bundle_id = "com.mydomain.mybrew"

apple_id {
    username = "<my_developer_id@application.com>"
    password = "@keychain:developer_id_application"
}

sign {
  application_identity = "Developer ID Application: my name (452534542)"
}
```

I can verify that the password is retrieve using:

```
security find-generic-password -w -s 'developer_id_application' -a '<my_developer_id@application.com>'
```

### Error:

```
   • archives         
      • creating                  archive=dist/appbrew_0.1.19_Darwin_x86_64.tar.gz
      • creating                  archive=dist/appbrew_0.1.19_Darwin_arm64.tar.gz
      • creating                  archive=dist/appbrew_0.1.19_Linux_i386.tar.gz
      • creating                  archive=dist/appbrew_0.1.19_Linux_x86_64.tar.gz
      • creating                  archive=dist/appbrew_0.1.19_Linux_arm64.tar.gz
   • creating source archive
   • linux packages   
   • snapcraft packages
   • calculating checksums
      • checksumming              file=appbrew_0.1.19_Linux_arm64.tar.gz
      • checksumming              file=appbrew_0.1.19_Darwin_arm64.tar.gz
      • checksumming              file=appbrew_0.1.19_Linux_x86_64.tar.gz
      • checksumming              file=appbrew_0.1.19_Darwin_x86_64.tar.gz
      • checksumming              file=appbrew_0.1.19_Linux_i386.tar.gz
   • signing artifacts
      • signing                   cmd=[gon gon.hcl]
      • ==> ✏️  Signing files...
 cmd=gon
      • ❗️ Error signing files:

error signing:

.: bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable

 cmd=gon
   ⨯ release failed after 3.49s error=sign: gon failed
```

Answer (score 1):

Your config should probably be something like:

```yaml
builds:
- binary: foo
  id: foo
  goos:
  - linux
  - windows
  goarch:
  - amd64
# separated build for macos only
- binary: foo
  id: foo-macos
  goos:
  - darwin
  goarch:
  - amd64
signs:
  - signature: "${artifact}.dmg"
    ids:
    - foo-macos
    cmd: gon
    args:
    - gon.hcl
    artifacts: all
```

notice that signing is done in the `signs` step, not in the `builds` like in your config.

More info in [Gon's repository](https://github.com/mitchellh/gon#usage-with-goreleaser).